# Does Ubuntu automatically delete older versions of software when there is an Update for them?

Tags: 12.04

I run 12.04 LTS and was wondering if by updating my Firmware, do the old versions delete or will it all build up in my system and take up space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing packages are generally overwritten when they are upgraded. Scenarios which can lead to the update taking up more space are:

- The updated package is larger in size
- it might come with additional dependencies that have to be pulled in first

---

It's important to know that this is valid for most packages but not all. Kernel upgrades, for instance, will not automatically remove the previous version. This makes it possible for the user to revert to a previous kernel if something went wrong in the course of the installation or if there are incompatibilities with the system.

This is what might have happened to your system given that you are talking about "firmware".

Please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) for more information on removing old kernel versions.

Comment: thank you because it confused me at first when I seen update manager for the first time saying about adding 562mb.